# Hadoop jvm process hangs without any error message,

Tags: java, hadoop, jvm

Hadoop jvm process hangs without any error message,
I want to take a look into what JVM processes are doing (where they are stuck).

When I program in C++, I used GDB that can be attached to a running process and show the call stack of the threads.

How can I do the same thing for JVM?

Comment: JDB is a good tool for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use following command

```
kill -3 [PID]
```

This will print stack traces of all threads to the console of your java process. Another option is to use **jstack** utility which is bundled with jdk. Jstack does the same thing.

If it doesn't help then profilers should help. They can gather a lot more data than one thread dump.